# Get multiple api calls from a device in a single R code

Tags: r, dataframe, api, multiple-instances

I am currently retrieving some numeric data from an api of a device. The code runs perfectly without errors however NOW i want to fetch data from multiple devices in a single code i.e multiple api calls if i am not wrong. These would be more than 50 calls since there are 50 devices.

I am running the following code curently for one device :

```
    url <-"https://example.com/api/GetDataBynum?num=ABCDevice.device#.parameter"
    geturl <-httr::GET(url,add_headers(.headers=c('key'='')))
    apidetails1<-content(geturl,"text", encoding ="UTF-8")
```

#and this one for second device number and so on which is inefficient

```
    url2 <-"https://example.com/api/GetDataBynum?num=ABCDevice.device#.parameter"
    geturl2 <-httr::GET(url2,add_headers(.headers=c('key'='')))
    apidetails2<-content(geturl2,"text", encoding ="UTF-8")
```

Is there any way to run multiple apis in single code ?

Comment: You have to use a loop or `lapply` command. Which part of the code changes for multiple devices?

Comment: Hey ronak as always you have been helpful. I have edited the question. Basically i need to extend the code for multiple apis. As a novice, I will be simply adding replica of the first code and then subsequently pasting a long inefficient code which is not desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a vector of url's and use it in `lapply` :

```
library(httr)
url <- sprintf('https://example.com/api/GetDataBynum?num=ABCDevice.device%s.parameter', data$dataf)

lapply(urls, function(x) {
  geturl <- GET(x,add_headers(.headers=c('key'='')))  
  content(geturl,"text", encoding ="UTF-8")
}) -> result
```

If you want to combine the data into one dataframe you can do `result <- do.call(rbind, result)`.

Comment: Pardon for not explicitly explaining the url format, this would be the correct format for URL and i need to change "device#" in the link as loop element so every iteration put device number in url. i have saved device# in the dataframe.  https://example.com/api/GetDataBynum?num=ABCDevice.device#.parameter

Comment: So url would be : `https://example.com/api/GetDataBynum?num=ABCDevice.device1.parameter` and `"https://example.com/api/GetDataBynum?num=ABCDevice.device2.parameter` and so on ? Would using `url <- sprintf('https://example.com/api/GetDataBynum?num=ABCDevice.device%d.parameter', 1:2)` work?

Comment: actually the device numbers are not ascending or descending and thats a problem for example deivce1235 then device 2367 and so on..

Comment: Where are those device numbers stored? Is it present somewhere?

Comment: yesssss i have saved them in a data frame

Comment: Right then, load that data into R and do `url <- sprintf('https://example.com/api/GetDataBynum?num=ABCDevice.device%d.parameter', data$device_number)` assuming the dataframe name is `data` and column name is `device_number`, change it according to your actual data.

Comment: this is generating error with %d and when i use %e it says too few arguments

Comment: What is the error that you get? Try using `%s`. If it still doesn't work please provide sample of your data with `dput` i.e `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: structure(list(dataf = c("18012102200210", "18012102200249", 
"18030202200196")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"). I just created a data frame with few device number to check if that works

Comment: with %s it is too few arguments.. are we doing some mistake in the end of sprintf ? i.e near  data$device_number ?

Comment: You should use the column name which is `data$dataf`. See my updated answer.

Comment: same  too few arguments error :( i guess this needs some alteration

Comment: my baddd i am also adding timestamp which has extra % sign thats why may be it is generating few argument error. Final final url is https://example.com/api/GetDataBynum?num=ABCDevice.device#.parameter&from=2021-02-01T00:00:00%2B08:00&to=2021-03-01T00:00:00%2B08:00', data$dataf)

Comment: without adding timestamp info its working

Comment: hey ronak. what if i associate every device a serial in ascending order and apply the following code result_list <- vector(mode="list", length=200)
for(deviceid in 0:200) {
    this_url <- paste0("https://example.com/api/GetDataBynum?num=ABCDevice.deviceid.parameter&from=2021-02-01T00:00:00%2B08:00&to=2021-03-01T00:00:00%2B08:00", deviceid)
    result_list[[deviceid]] <- fromJSON(this_url)
}
result <- do.call(rbind, result_list)